# Getting error while generating report in Sonarqube-9.4

Tags: sonarqube, source-code-protection, devsecops

I was scanning DotNet application using Sonarqube. Sonarscaner.MSBuild.exe begin, MSbuild and end, all 3 executed successfully in the same project root path. But while trying to access the report on Sonar server i get following error.

````
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to extract report AYD0z6QfJAqVN7fqeTDx from database
    at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.step.ExtractReportStep.execute(ExtractReportStep.java:73)
    at org.sonar.ce.task.step.ComputationStepExecutor.executeStep(ComputationStepExecutor.java:80)
    at org.sonar.ce.task.step.ComputationStepExecutor.executeSteps(ComputationStepExecutor.java:71)
    at org.sonar.ce.task.step.ComputationStepExecutor.execute(ComputationStepExecutor.java:58)
    at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.taskprocessor.ReportTaskProcessor.process(ReportTaskProcessor.java:75)
    at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl$ExecuteTask.executeTask(CeWorkerImpl.java:212)
    at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl$ExecuteTask.run(CeWorkerImpl.java:194)
    at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl.findAndProcessTask(CeWorkerImpl.java:160)
    at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl$TrackRunningState.get(CeWorkerImpl.java:135)
    at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl.call(CeWorkerImpl.java:87)
    at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl.call(CeWorkerImpl.java:53)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:131)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:74)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:82)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry size (expected 1342191808 but got 14528 bytes)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.readEnd(ZipInputStream.java:400)
    at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:199)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
    at org.sonar.api.internal.apachecommons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1309)
    at org.sonar.api.internal.apachecommons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:978)
    at org.sonar.api.internal.apachecommons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1282)
    at org.sonar.api.internal.apachecommons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:953)
    at org.sonar.api.utils.ZipUtils.copy(ZipUtils.java:152)
    at org.sonar.api.utils.ZipUtils.unzipEntry(ZipUtils.java:102)
    at org.sonar.api.utils.ZipUtils.unzip(ZipUtils.java:86)
    at org.sonar.api.utils.ZipUtils.unzip(ZipUtils.java:63)
    at org.sonar.ce.task.projectanalysis.step.ExtractReportStep.execute(ExtractReportStep.java:71)
    ... 19 more```
````

Answer (score 0):

It seems there was a problem with transferring report from CLI to sonar server.
Scanning again and generating report seems to have solved the problem.